# Unable to backup Function/Web App using Azure Cli az webapp config backup create

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-function-app, azure-appservice, azure-cli2

I am facing an issue when executing the Azure Cli command to backup my Azure App Service:

Cli Command :

az webapp config backup create --resource-group  --webapp-name  
--backup-name testbackup --container-url

**I generated a new SaS key to be passed along with the command.**

Is this the correct approach.

Cli Output:

`{ "backupId": 64862, "backupItemName": "testbackup", "blobName": "testbackup", "correlationId": "3e9ae4d0-9aa9-46e0-9926-53ec1ef6ef2c", "created": "2020-09-22T08:50:35.555268+00:00", "databases": null, "finishedTimeStamp": null, "id": "value", "kind": null, "lastRestoreTimeStamp": null, "location": "Central US", "log": null, "name": "testbackuppr", "resourceGroup": "RG-POC", "scheduled": false, **"sizeInBytes": 0,** "status": "Created", "storageAccountUrl": "", "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites", "websiteSizeInBytes": null }`

Log Information in the Portal : Storage access failed. The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.. Please delete and recreate backup schedule to mitigate.

[image: Error Message when executing the command]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like something is not right with the Storage account or its access. Before you execute the `az webapp config backup create` command, please make sure that you have a valid Storage account, a storage container and a SAS token with the appropriate expiry date. The SAS token can be generated with the `az storage container generate-sas` command.

The following script worked for me:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

groupname="myResourceGroup"
planname="myAppServicePlan"
webappname=mywebapp$RANDOM
storagename=mywebappstorage$RANDOM
location="WestEurope"
container="appbackup"
backupname="backup1"
expirydate=$(date -I -d "$(date) + 1 month")

# Create a Resource Group 
az group create --name $groupname --location $location

# Create a Storage Account
az storage account create --name $storagename --resource-group $groupname --location $location \
--sku Standard_LRS

# Create a storage container
az storage container create --account-name $storagename --name $container

# Generates an SAS token for the storage container, valid for one month.
# NOTE: You can use the same SAS token to make backups in App Service until --expiry
sastoken=$(az storage container generate-sas --account-name $storagename --name $container \
--expiry $expirydate --permissions rwdl --output tsv)

# Construct the SAS URL for the container
sasurl=https://$storagename.blob.core.windows.net/$container?$sastoken

# Create an App Service plan in Standard tier. Standard tier allows one backup per day.
az appservice plan create --name $planname --resource-group $groupname --location $location \
--sku S1

# Create a web app
az webapp create --name $webappname --plan $planname --resource-group $groupname

# Create a one-time backup
az webapp config backup create --resource-group $groupname --webapp-name $webappname \
--backup-name $backupname --container-url $sasurl

# List statuses of all backups that are complete or currently executing.
az webapp config backup list --resource-group $groupname --webapp-name $webappname
```

Output would be similar to:
[image: Output]

References:

- [Back up an app using Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scripts/cli-backup-onetime)
- [az webapp config backup create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/config/backup?view=azure-cli-latest#az_webapp_config_backup_create)
- [az storage container generate-sas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/container?view=azure-cli-latest#az_storage_container_generate_sas)